# soccer 1X2 odds to Asian Handicap conversion

Tags: excel

Can anyone help .
I now know how to convert Home,Draw,Away probabilities to Asian handicap lines usin excel e.g.:
At first let’s take a look at the simpler situations where the handicap is half a goal or zero
goals (=no advatage for either team).
Handicaps marked as 0:0 are identical to moneyline bets (which is a term used in
America for this type of bet). In moneyline you bet on which team will win the game.
And if the game ends with a draw the stakes will (usually) be fully refunded. And
because the result from refunded stake is exactly the same as if the bet was never placed,
the possibility of draw can be excluded from the set.
The true odds (in decimal presentation) for moneyline can be derived from the
probabilities of home win, draw and away win in the following way:
Home Odds = (1 - p0) / p1
Away Odds = (1 - p0) / p2,
where p1 is the probability for home win (a value between 0 and 1), p0 the probability for
draw (0..1) and p2 the probability for away win (0..1).
Numerical example:

```
If 1X2-probabilities for a game are 45% (= 0.45), 30% (= 0.30) and 25% (=0.25),
moneyline odds would be: 4
Home Odds = (1 - 0.30) / 0.45 = 1.56
Away Odds = (1 - 0.30) / 0.25 = 2.80
```

Now I'm stuck tryin to do the same for the over and under Asian goal lines.
what I am tryin to achieve is how this website does it

https://www.totalcorner.com/page/fulltime-asian-handicap-calculator

remember I know 1x2 Asian handicap formula and what I'm asking is help with the over/under goal lines.
Thanks in advance